difference between https-listner and server-ssl-contexts
whats is the difference between <https-listener and (wildlfy stand alone)
in wildfly 20 admin team wrote the list of ciphers on this tag https-listener
in wiildlfy 26 admin team wrote the list of ciphers on this tag server-ssl-contexts
they left this tag https-listener empty
Adavnace thanks

whats is the difference between <https-listener and server-ssl-contexts
(wildlfy stand alone)
in wildfly 20 admin team wrote the list of ciphers on this tag https-listener
in wiildlfy 26 admin team wrote the list of ciphers on this tag server-ssl-contexts ;
they left this tag https-listener empty Adavnace thanks
